# Dommousescroller not woring in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

This function is working fine in all browser except in IE though this function is working in IE only in downward direction $(window).mousewheel (function(event) 
   this is the site link where you can test below  code functionality
   https://staging.carpetcourt.nz/

Below is my js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // scroll function
 var mouseEvent = "DOMMouseScroll mousewheel wheel";
    if( $('body').hasClass('mozilla') ){
        mouseEvent = "DOMMouseScroll";
    }
    var isDoingStuff = false;
    $(window).bind(mouseEvent, function(event){
        console.log(event.originalEvent.deltaY);
        $('body').find('.scroll-sec').show();
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();
        if( windowWidth > 767){
            var headerHeight = parseInt( $('#cc-navbar').outerHeight() ) || 0;
            if( $('body').hasClass('onepage-scroll') ){
                event.preventDefault();
                var currentdiv = $('body').find('.scroll-sec.active');
                var current_id = $('body').find('.scroll-sec.active').attr('id');
                var id_num = parseInt(current_id.split(/[-]+/).pop());
                console.log(event.originalEvent.wheelDelta);
                 if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
                    //scrolled up
                    if( $('.site-footer').hasClass('at-bottom') ){
                        if(isDoingStuff) { return; }
                        isDoingStuff = true;
                        currentdiv.removeClass('active');
                        // currentdiv.prev('.scroll-sec').addClass('active');
                        $('body').find('.site-footer').removeClass('at-bottom');
                        $('body').find('.slier-menu-right a').removeClass('active');
                        id_num -= 1;
                        $('body').find('.slier-menu-right').find('a[href="#section-'+id_num+'"]').addClass('active');
                        currentdiv.css("transform", "translateY(100%)");
                        $('body').find('.site-footer').css("transform", "translateY(100%)");
                        $('body').find('#section-'+id_num).css("transform", "translateY(0)");
                        $('body').find('#section-'+id_num).addClass('active');
                        setTimeout(function() {isDoingStuff = false;}, 150);
                    }else if (!$('#section-0').hasClass("active")){
                        if(isDoingStuff) { return; }
                        isDoingStuff = true;
                        // console.log('scrolled up');
                        currentdiv.removeClass('active');
                        $('body').find('.site-footer').removeClass('at-bottom');
                        currentdiv.css("transform", "translateY(100%)");
                        $('body').find('.site-footer').css("transform", "translateY(100%)");
                        currentdiv.prevAll('.scroll-sec').css("transform", "translateY(-100%)");
                        $('body').find('.slier-menu-right a').removeClass('active');
                        id_num -= 1;
                        $('body').find('.slier-menu-right').find('a[href="#section-'+id_num+'"]').addClass('active');
                        $('body').find('#section-'+id_num).addClass('active');
                        $('body').find('#section-'+id_num).css("transform", "translateY(0)");
                        setTimeout(function() {isDoingStuff = false;}, 150);
                        $('.scroll-sec').find('.cc-scroll-down').remove();
                        $('.scroll-sec.active').append('<a class="cc-scroll-down" href="#"><span></span></a>');
                        if( id_num == 0 ){
                            if( $('nav.navbar-fixed-top').hasClass('shrink') ){
                                $('nav.navbar-fixed-top').removeClass('shrink');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    //scrolled down
                    if ($('#section-0').hasClass("active")){
                        if( !$('nav.navbar-fixed-top').hasClass('shrink') ){
                            $('nav.navbar-fixed-top').addClass('shrink');
                        }
                    }
                    if (!$('.prefooter-section').hasClass("active")){
                        if(isDoingStuff) { return; }
                        isDoingStuff = true;
                        // console.log('scrolled down');
                        currentdiv.removeClass('active');
                        id_num += 1;
                        $('body').find('#section-'+id_num).addClass('active');
                        if( !$('.prefooter-section').hasClass('active') ){
                            currentdiv.css("transform", "translateY(-100%)");
                            currentdiv.nextAll('.scroll-sec').css("transform", "translateY(100%)");
                            $('body').find('.slier-menu-right a').removeClass('active');
                            $('body').find('.slier-menu-right').find('a[href="#section-'+id_num+'"]').addClass('active');
                            $('body').find('#section-'+id_num).css("transform", "translateY(0)");
                            $('.scroll-sec').find('.cc-scroll-down').remove();
                            $('.scroll-sec.active').append('<a class="cc-scroll-down" href="#"><span></span></a>');
                        }else{
                            $('body').find('.prefooter-section').css('height', 'auto');
                            var prefooterHeight = parseInt( $('body').find('.prefooter-section').outerHeight() ) || 0;
                            var footerHeight = parseInt( $('.site-footer').outerHeight() ) || 0;
                            var totalHeight = prefooterHeight+footerHeight;
                            $('body').find('.slier-menu-right a').removeClass('active');
                            $('body').find('.slier-menu-right').find('a[href="#section-'+id_num+'"]').addClass('active');
                            currentdiv.css("transform", "translateY(-"+totalHeight+"px)");
                            $('.prefooter-section').css("transform", "translateY(-"+footerHeight+"px)");
                            $('body').find('.site-footer').css("transform", "translateY(0)");
                            $('body').find('.site-footer').addClass('at-bottom');
                        }
                        setTimeout(function() {isDoingStuff = false;}, 150);
                        // if( !$('.prefooter-section').hasClass('active') ){}
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            console.log('scrolled just');
        }
      });
      });
```